# ActivityCompat always undefined on android.support.v4.app

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

Recently I have created native script angular app. I'm trying to get read permissions for SMS but getting below error

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestPermissions' of undefined

```
(<any>android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat).requestPermissions(app.android.context,
        [(<any>android).Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS], REQUEST_REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS);
```

added below lines to manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

I have tried nativescript-permissions plugin it is working fine but I wanted to try without plugin

Update: Working code

```
    const activity = app.android.foregroundActivity || app.android.startActivity;
    (<any>androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat).requestPermissions(activity,
        [(<any>android).Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS], REQUEST_REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS);

    // or
    activity.requestPermissions(
        [(<any>android).Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS], REQUEST_REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With AndroidX support in {N} 6 and above, `android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat` no longer exists. It should be `androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly with context obj

```
context.requestPermissions(new String[] {
      Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
  }, REQUEST_REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS);
```